# replacing a bunch of lines in a bunch of files

Tags: regex

Let's say I have some thousands of HTML files with some text inside 'em (articles, actually). Besides, let's say there are all sorts of scripts, styles, counters, other crap inside these HTMLs, somewhere above the actual text.

And my task is to replace **everything** that goes from the very beginning until a certain tag – i.e., we start with `<head>` and end with `<div class="StoryGoesBelow">` with a clear

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
```

block.

Is there any regex way I can do this? Vim? Any other editor? Scripting language?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest using an HTML parser.

Comment: Which language are you using for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Asking for a way to implement what you think is the best solution *may* not be the best question to ask.

Comment: @RamchandraApte: I don't think that's such a good idea. A regex would be much simpler here (with a parser you'd have to parse the tree, find the first relevant `div` tag, remove all tags and content before it etc...)

Comment: @TimPietzcker If you did that you *may* end up with invalid HTML. In general when parsing complex nested document structures like HTML, if you want to reuse your code or if you have flexible requirements use a parser. But you have to use your own judgement as to whether its trivial enough for regexp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest regex for this would be `(?s)\A.*?(?=<div class="StoryGoesBelow">)` (assuming you want to keep the `<div>` tag). Replace that with the text from your question.

**Explanation:**

```
(?s)   # Allow the dot to match newlines
\A     # Anchor the search at the start of the string
.*?    # Match any number of characters, as few as possible
(?=<div class="StoryGoesBelow">)  # and stop right before this <div>
```

This will fail, of course, if the text `<div class="StoryGoesBelow">` could also occur in a comment or a literal string somewhere above the actual tag.

Comment: Tim, thanks!

Can it work with Perl via something like that, what do you think?

`perl -pi -w -e 's/(?s)\A.*?(?=<div class="StoryGoesBelow">)//g;' *.html`

Comment: @AS: I don't know Perl, so I'm not sure about this syntax, but you definitely don't need the `g` modifier and should use the `s` modifier instead (and remove the `(?s)` at the start).

Comment: the problem is that doesn't work :(. which language can you suggest to use that regex with?

Comment: Whatever you're comfortable with - that regex should work in pretty much all modern languages except JavaScript (but you need to use the language-specific syntax for the `s` modifier). Personally, I'd simply use an editor for this (UltraEdit can do this out of the box, RegexBuddy/PowerGREP give you more control...)

Comment: Tim, I've tried it in BBEdit (an editor for OS X, which supports operations on multiple files), and it's actually worked, so thank you!

Comment: Just in case anyone will need a similar regex for deleting everything from the certain point till the end of a document, here it goes: `(?s)<div class="StoryGoesAbove">.*?(?=\Z)`